# Know the image user is viewing in slimbox2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, slimbox

I have an image gallery which uses slimbox2.js

I want to know which image the user is viewing at a given time. How do I get the currently viewing image? (Note user need not click on every single image to view, once he clicks a single image and the slideshow loads he can use the mouse clicks or the arrow keys to browse through images in the gallery)

Example: *The user clicks on the first image in the gallery. I can add a click event listener and get this event, to record that the user viewed the first image. But what happens if the user selects to click the next button in slimbox2 and view the next image.*

The user viewed the second image but I don't know, that user viewed it. How can I capture this event?

Another approach I thought of was to get the image which slimbox2 loads into it's view, Is there any event triggered at this moment?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL of the image using jQuery..

```
jQuery("#lbImage").css("background-image").toString().replace('url(','').replace(")","")
```

Comment: slimbox uses background-image CSS property to display the images in a slide-show. At any event, you can have the image url currently displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<img class="img-fade" src="img/message.png" id="messages" />
$('#messages').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
}
```

In the above function try to get the username as you want. When its get clicked you could record the user name.